# VOIP phone working intermittently

Tags: voip, sip, polycom

I'm having problems with my Polycom VVX400 phones. It's the first time i've configured them to work with Aircall.io, our SIP provider.

I have them registered just fine and I can make calls, but when I dial it, it rings and works once (I can hear and speak), then if I hang up and dial it again, I can no longer connect to it. I get an audio message saying this number is not registered. If I wait a few minutes, it starts working again.

It sounds like a connectivity issue. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Router. Firewall. Network setup? This sounds like a network related issue but without logs or more details can't help.

Comment: The audio message must be coming from the provider, the phones don't usually play error messages on their own. Check with your provider, and if you really believe that it's a firewall, network or routing issue, provide logs and a more concrete question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think there is a possibility of networking/firewall issue or there's something that network routing is not working from the box. You should check networking in general.

Or may be SIP provider is unreachable.